# Python: Identification of which excel cell is involved

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am still a beginner with Python.

I want to change for example banana the current value from 1 to x (with openpyxl or xlsxwriter?).
How do I find out the corresponding cell (in the current case C02) when the query is for banana, so I can say "change cell C02 to x".

I hope my concern has become clear.

[pic of simple excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06XwS.png)

Comment: Please include what code you've written so far.

Comment: Your question needs more clarification! Please, take a look at "How to Ask A Good Question" (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It can help you to enhance your question.